# probability of a player drawing a certain suit in a card game

Tags: probability, statistics

4 players are playing cards. The cards are dealt out equally to them. If player 1 and player 2 have a total of 6 spades among them, what is the probability of player 3 having 2 of the remaining 7 spades?

Assuming this is a normal deck of cards

(7C2 x 39C11)/52C13

I got a probability of 0.055427 that player 3 has 2 of the remaining 7 spades.

Comment: How did you get that probability?

Comment: @MathLover I have included the choice equation that I used

Comment: any $\LaTeX$, OP?

Comment: That is not correct. You have to think in terms of number of cards left to choose your spades from.

Answer (score 1):

Player $1$ and $2$ have total of $6$ spades out of $26$ cards dealt to them. We already know that.

So there are $7$ spades in $26$ cards distributed to player $3$ and $4$.

Probability of player $3$ being dealt $2$ spades $= \displaystyle \frac {{7 \choose 2} \times {19 \choose 11}}{26 \choose 13}$